# Commanding Realterm from VB.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I code the following .lnk shortcut to run directly from Visual Studio VB commandbutton1? thank you

"C:\Program Files (x86)\BEL\Realterm\realterm.exe" Baud=4800 Data=7E2 Port=1 timestamp=4 capfile=C:\Cap\LPSample1.txt capsecs=35 capture=1 Sendfile=C:\Cap\Mes.rae Senddly=3000 Sendrep=10 CapQuit

Comment: Nobody is going to do your work for you.  Give it a shot yourself.  If you still have trouble, show us what you tried and we'll try to help.

Comment: You have a command line with parameters.  You can either create a shell command or run cmd.exe with parameters using a process class.  You need to specify the full path of cmd.exe (which is in the c:\windows folder).

Comment: Sam nobody is asking for the solution, but some guidance to the solution, take for example Jdweng response, you could learn from his professional response. At the point someone is reaching out on the boards would suggest they are stumped and need a different perspective  If you have nothing constructive to add, save the server space.. Thanks JD, that's what I was looking for.